# Can you compare the values of two ampscript variables?

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript

I'm coding a SFMC preference center and I have a first name variable (FirstName) that is taken from the SFCRM Contact record. I also have a second first name field (MC_FirstName) if people want to change their name. I ONLY want to update the MC_FirstName field in CRM if it is different from the @FirstName field. But this isn't working:

```
IF @MC_FirstName != @FirstName then
  set @updateFirstNameRecord = UpdateSingleSalesforceObject(
    @targetObject, @subkey,
    "MC_First_Name__c", @MC_FirstName
    )
ENDIF
```

Am I missing some understanding about the ability of ampscript to compare variable values?

Comment: How is your code "not working"?

Comment: So this problem was me having an error in my data and how the variables were set. You absolutely CAN compare two ampscript variables.

Answer (score 0):

The logical operators are listed here: [AMPscript Language Elements](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.mc-programmatic-content.meta/mc-programmatic-content/languageElements.htm)

> Comparison operators compare values. These operators are case-insensitive.
>
> == Is equal to
> != Is not equal to
> > Greater than
> < Less Than
> >= Greater than or equal to
> <= Less than or equal to

To test this have you printed your variables to ensure everything is what is expected

```
%%=v(@Firstname)=%%
%%=v(@MC_Firstname)=%%
%%=v(@targetobject)=%%
%%=v(@subkey)=%%
```